# Format a string using dictionary unpacking (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting, string-formatting

```
mystr = '{1} {0}'
mydict = {'0': '5', '1': 'ZIDANE'}
result = mystr.format(**mydict)
```

Which raises:

> IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

I can do the following:

```
mystr = '{name} {number}'
mydict = {'number': '5', 'name': 'ZIDANE'}
result = mystr.format(**mydict)
```

This gives me the result: `ZIDANE 5`

How can I achieve the same for:

```
mystr = '{1} {0}'
mydict = {'0': '5', '1': 'ZIDANE'}
```

Comment: `mystr.format(*reversed(mydict.values()))`

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  The docs say: The *field_name* itself begins with an *arg_name* that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. ... Because *arg_name* is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings `'10'` or `':-]'`) within a format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the keys are (string) of integer and this is in **conflict** with the notation for a substitution with `list` (2nd example). This is due (I guess) by the implementation of `__getitem__`, [here](https://pyformat.info/) some more examples.

Here with non-integer keys:

```
mydict = {'0.': '5', '1.': 'ZIDANE'}  # with float-keys it works
print('{d[0.]} {d[1.]}'.format(d=mydict))
```

Here an example with a list

```
mylst = ['5', 'ZIDANE']
print('{l[0]} {l[1]}'.format(l=mylst))
```

A similar side-effect is encountered with dictionaries:

```
print(dict(a=5, b='ZIDANE'))
#{'a': 5, 'b': 'ZIDANE'}
print(dict(1=5, 2='ZIDANE'))
#SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
print(dict('1'=5, '2'='ZIDANE'))
#SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```